# Calculate folder size without counting links

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, symbolic-link, hardlink, junction

I need to calculate the size of "real" files created under a folder (and its sub-folders) on an NTFS drive, where "real" is all files that are not present because of hard/soft-links, junctions etc.

Is there currently any tool that will do this? (command-line or graphical)

**More details:**

I guess such a capability will be useful only under the right circumstances, so, to avoid questions due to speculations on how I "really want to use it", I'll mention my use case in advance...

I've started using [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/) and I'm trying to evaluate actual disk usage. Given that the `node_modules` folder (when created by `pnpm`) contains folders that are links to `pnpm`'s store, I know that files in those folders should not be counted. [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) seems to ignore these folders, but I need to be sure about this.

**Update (2019/12/02):**

It seems to be more complicated than I thought. See this issue: [Add size/disk usage benchmarks](https://github.com/pnpm/benchmarks-of-javascript-package-managers/issues/13).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use [FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_get_ntfs_file_record).  Links are properties of the file record.

As a bonus, it will enumerate things that the `dir` command won't show ($MFT, $LogFile, etc).

Comment: Sorry, that's not a tool. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hmm.  I suppose I could wrap a CLI around it for you.  But... To enumerate all the files on disk, especially using the MFT, requires admin privileges.  If I made it, would you be comfortable running it?

Answer (score 0):

Won't something like this work for you?

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'node_modules' | 
? { $_.LinkType -eq $Null } | 
Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
```

`$_.LinkType -eq $Null` filters out all link types.

Answer (score 0):

using du isn't enough to not chase links.
you can use this code :

```
find /home/somedirectory/ -exec du -s {} + | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print (total / 1024 / 1024) "MB"}'
```